How to make two distinct shapes's background colors merge in Illustrator?
So I'm trying to create the RGB color diagram in Adobe Illustrator, I created 3 elipses 366px wide and tall (so they're effectivelly circumferences).
Then, I changed the background color of one of elipse 1 to pure red (255,0,0) , the background color of elipse 2 to pure green (0,255,0) and the background color of elipse 3 to pure blue (0,0,255).
Then I put them overlapping each other like in this image:

But as each has an opaque background the colors just stay on top of each other and I can't see the color that's behind.
I tried giving a lower opacity to each shape, but then it's not pure colors anymore, and they still only blend according to the respective layers of each shape.
How can I make the colors merge (as in the image I showed) without having to select each of the circumference intersections and changing the color od each intersection individually?
I want the background colors to merge and create a new color when the shapes overlap.
Can someone help me?

Set the blend mode of the circles to Difference or Exclusion or Screen:


I think screen is better

Added @joojaa I honestly didn't go through all the modes. :) They all look identical - and show the same RGB values.

Well it depends on the color settings a bit, difference and exclusion can become wrong with some settings screen should be right in all cases as its the sortof correct operation for this task and it works with similar logic with other tints. Try making for example red not entirely pure

Yeah I can see muddy colors will change the Difference and Exclusion a bit. But muddy colors would defeat the purpose of the art :) I do see your point about Screen though.

So the benefit is that screen would also sortof work in a CMYK document to do this.

Which it "sort of" does.. it's just the base RGB that's not correct in CMYK (colors, especially the green, shift considerably) :) At least in legacy Illustrator.

Yes obviously. But just in case you need to proint a document about rgb colors with a offset printer. Best you can do really.

Others have already shown that pure full brightness R, pure full brightness G and pure full brightness B can be mixed as you show in your example with several blending modes. Unfortunately  if you have arbitary RGB colors, say (r1,g1,b1, (r2,g2,b2) and (r3,g3,b3) you cannot get mix (r1+r2+r3, g1+g2+g3, b1+b2+b3)with Illustrator's blending modes because there's not available mode ADD i.e. "linear addition"
If you need RGB blending "linear addition" you must use other software. Free vector drawing tool Inkscape doesn't have it. But Affinity Designer does:

Also Photoshop and GIMP have it, but those programs are for raster images. I guess they would still be useful if you need only 3 circles.
The common RGB colors cannot have higher numbers than 255. If the sum is higher, the result is clipped to 255. I guess it would cause in artistic works an unpleasing visual effect which would look worse than what's got by using other blending modes and that's why ADD is not included. But that's a guess.
Beware: If you are going to print something the colors would behave totally differently. Generally CMYK printing cannot make as bright colors as what's seen on RGB computer screens.
